# jQuery Mixing on.click with contains and exact match

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need a possibility to get the exact match of a search string in a `on.click` handler. This is what I have now,

```
$("#wrapper").on("click", "label:contains('SEARCH') ~ .material > .icon", function (e) {
```

Problem is, that "contains" matches all words with Label containing "SEARCH".

> E.g. "Search", "Searchsting", "Searchsentence" and so on....

Any ideas?? Have spent a lot of time, to find a solution. E.g. mixing `:contains(''):not(:contains).` But with no success.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="field dco-uncommon has-required required dco-enabled" id="bss_options_5283" depend-id="20652" style="display: block;">
        <label class="label" for="select_5283"><span>SEARCH</span></label>
        <div class="control ">
            <select name="options[5283]" id="select_5283" class="product-custom-option admin__control-select required" data-selector="options[5283]" aria-required="true">
            <option value="">-- Please choose --</option>
            <option value="75108" price="0" depend-id="20659">Option 1</option>
            <option value="75111" price="35" depend-id="20662">Option 2</option>
            </select>                       
        </div>
         
        <div class="material">
          <span class="icon" style="background-image: url(amethyst_1646165.jpg)" data-title="Amethyst 1646165" title="Amethyst 1646165"></span>
          <span class="icon" style="background-image: url(apfel_1644435.jpg)" data-title="Apfel 1644435" title="Apfel 1644435"></span>
          <span class="icon" style="background-image: url(auster_1644480.jpg)" data-title="Auster 1644480" title="Auster 1644480"></span>
          <span class="icon" style="background-image: url(azure_1641085.jpg)" data-title="Azure 1641085" title="Azure 1641085"></span>
          <span class="icon" style="background-image: url(baltic_1645155.jpg)" data-title="Baltic 1645155" data-properties="" title="Baltic 1645155"></span>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show the HTML for Label?  :contains() pseudo-class as been removed from the specs and shouldn't be used. Also since you are already using jQuery, why you want to mix it with complex CSS selectors?

Comment: Please share the HTML part.

Comment: jQuery has no explicit selector for "contains _exactly_ this text content and nothing else." You would need to loop over your labels and access the textnode inside the span directly, and check what its value is. That will also mean you can't use event delegation any more. Or you do it the other way around - use event delegation to bind this handler to all icons inside _any_ such label, no matter what it contains - and then inside the callback, you access the label element first and check is text content, and then based on that you either proceed, or do nothing ...

Answer (score 0):

The logic you're looking for is not supported by jQuery, so I was able to get this library that extends jQuery and gives you exactly what you're looking for:

https://blog.mastykarz.nl/jquery-regex-filter/

This library allows you to use regex to filter values in your elements:

Then here we are using normal javascript regex to match the exact word: **^SEARCH$**

```js
// extend jquery
jQuery.extend(
    jQuery.expr[':'], {
        regex: function(a, i, m, r) {
            var r = new RegExp(m[3], 'i');
            return r.test(jQuery(a).text());
        }
    }
);
// extend jquery

$(function() {
  $("#wrapper").on("click", `label:regex('^SEARCH$')`, function (e) {
    console.log('This label contains the exact string "SEARCH"')
  })
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
    height: auto;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    padding: 2px;
}
label {
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <label for="">SEARCH</label>
    <label for="">SEARCHstring</label>
    <label for="">stringSEARCHother</label>
    <label for="">stringsearchother</label>
    <label for="">SEARCH</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Getting "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: regex"

Comment: What jQuery version are you using? Because you can see from this snippet that it works just fine

Comment: Using Magento 2.4.2 jQuery

Comment: Try using a higher version like the one in the snippet: **3.3.1**.. Or even the latest version if it will be compatible with your project